# Formatting poblem in vscode (Prettier)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, prettier

Using Javascript to code.

**This is what the prettier formatting does**

```
app.post(
    "/campgrounds",
    validateCampground,
    catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
        const newCampground = new Campground(req.body.campground);

        // console.log(newCampground.title)
        await newCampground.save();
        //
        res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${newCampground._id}`);
    })
);
```

**I want it to format like this instead**

```
app.post("/campgrounds",validateCampground,catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
        const newCampground = new Campground(req.body.campground);

        // console.log(newCampground.title)
        await newCampground.save();
        //
        res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${newCampground._id}`);
    })
);
```

I tried messing with the settings but nothing happens. also tried making the line limit much higher but did not work

If there is nothing prettier can do, maybe a suggestion of a better formatting extension on visual studio code.

Comment: Sry but personally I think the first one is more readable xD

Comment: You should use the first one, since it easier to read on small screens